# MPMoviePlayerController ignores MPMovieControlStyle.None in Swift

Tags: swift, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmoviewcontroller

I'm trying to autoplay a video in my app. The video needs to play without the controls.
I've set up the video and the settings, including MPMovieControlStyle.None but the video controls appear for about 2 seconds before disappearing. I have no idea why.
I've used this code (exact code) for another project and it works well, but here for some reason it will not.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    generateVideo()
}
func generateVideo () {

let movieURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType: "mp4")
    let videoFilePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: movieURL!)
    self.view.addSubview(MoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.view)
    self.view.sendSubviewToBack(MoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.view)
    MoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.contentURL = videoFilePath
    MoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = true
    MoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
    MoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    MoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.fullscreen = true
    MoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
    MoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.play()
    MoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One
    MoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFit
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I seem to have solved the problem. I loaded the storyboard via a different storyboard (our team insisted on it, to make merges less messy) and when I loaded my storyboard directly it worked every time.
I'll leave the question open meanwhile in case anyone has any insights as to why this happens. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking how the view is loaded I'm sure the problem is there.
I used a different layout with one Storyboard calling another storyboard and that was the source of the problem.